# Android: issue with the xml Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to create a browser app, and right now I'm trying to create the layout - which is basically, an `EditText` (as address bar), a `WebView` and a bar in the bottom. The problem that I can't make the bottom bar appear. Here is my `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <EditText 
          android:id="@+id/addressbar" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

     <com.android.ibrowser.myWebView  
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/browser"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

      <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/downBar"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height = "60px" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your WebView having the attribute `layout_weight`set to `"1"` and your bar at the bottom should appear

Comment: Thanks man it worked... But can you explain how the layout_weight affects the layout? Thanks.

Comment: `layout_weight` is used, if multiple layout elements have their height or width set to `fill_parent`. Another case for using this element is having an element after an element whose width (height) is set to `fill_parent` and would kick off the following element off the screen. Using the `layout_weight` you can easily manage the elements` sizes independent from the screen.